# Remove specific meta_data from product on woocommerce checkout

Tags: woocommerce

so - I have a couple of meta_data which I don't want to get transmitted. Actually with this snippet I am able to do this on woocommerce order view. As I have connected an ERP this won't work there.

```
add_filter( "woocommerce_order_item_get_formatted_meta_data","unset_specific_order_item_meta_data", 10, 2);
function unset_specific_order_item_meta_data($formatted_meta, $item){
foreach( $formatted_meta as $key => $meta ){
    if( in_array( $meta->key, array("length", "surface", "amount") ) )
        unset($formatted_meta[$key]);
}
return $formatted_meta;
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this with woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta? So that the specific meta_data (like length, surface, amount) isn't in the order in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

The [woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/94a65db0b17b32a060174e8be50eaadaaffec3be/includes/class-wc-checkout.php#L396) hook is meant to save custom meta data, unsetting meta data doesn't work here. However you can use [delete_meta_data](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Data.html#method_delete_meta_data) like this:

```
add_action("woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta", "custom_woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta", 10, 2);
function custom_woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta($order_id, $data) {
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    if ($order) {
        $meta_data_keys = array("length", "surface", "amount");
        foreach ($meta_data_keys as $meta_data_key) {
            $order->delete_meta_data($meta_data_key);
        }
    }
}
```